# Do I need Windows AIK to integrate a winqual driver into install.wim?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, windows-installation, installation-media

I have windows7 ultimate 64bit installed on my pc. I have the bootable usb setup files for windows 7 ultimate 64bit. I want to integrate some WinQUal drivers into the setup files.

Can I do this with Dism alone or do I need to download Windows AIK for it.

All I need is to integrate few winqual drivers specific to my pc into the installation media. And replace the install.wim to the bootable usb and install the operating system with it, So I can have the drivers.

Comment: It's easier if you have AIK.  The alternative is you apply your current image to a machine, you install the drivers, then you generalize the image, and generate a new image with DISM.  AIK allows you to skip that entire process.

Comment: @Ramhound nope, updating a WIM with same version as os doesn't require ADK/AIK. It only wastes a lot of space for nothing

Comment: I personally have never done it any other way.  I suppose I learn something everyday.

Comment: @Ramhound now you know it. If you try to use DISM from an older windows to work with a newer install.wim you can get errors like 0xc0000135. Here you need the newer ADK/AIK.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows 7 and try to update a Windows 7 install.wim, you don't need the ADK. The ADK is useful if you want to service a WIM from a higher Windows version (Windows 8.1 on Windows 7). This can be only done by the newer DISM.exe from the ADK.